# Domus Memory Used Issue With Xen On CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, xen, libvirt, virsh

Anyone know why I'm receiving this error? I compiled latest libvirt from source, I also tried with various rpm.

I would like to get memory used by domus and it looks like it's not working with Xen 3 on CentOS 5.

```
virsh #  dommemstat mydomainname
error: Failed to get memory statistics for domain mydomainname
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainMemoryStats

virsh # domcontrol mydomainname
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainGetControlInfo
```

Any help will be appreciated.